# Postgresql: unique value within the same high-level key(s) but different directly subkey

Tags: postgresql, unique, multiple-columns

I have a table like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tt
(key1     integer
,key2     integer
,data     varchar(8)

,CONSTRAINT cst_tt_key1_key2 UNIQUE (key1, key2)
);

CREATE INDEX idx_tt_data_trigram
    ON data
 USING gist(data gist_trgm_ops);
```

I want to have unique value of `data` under the same value of `key1`.

In order words, the following records are possible.

```
1,  1,  "Postgres"
2,  1,  "Postgres"
```

However, the following records are not permitted.

```
1,  1,  "Postgres"
1,  2,  "Postgres"
```

Any idea how to do it using `CHECK` or `CONSTRAINT`?

Comment: `create unique index on tt (key2, data)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a unique index.

```
create unique index on tt(key1, data)
```

Comment: A unique constraint and a unique index are essentially the same thing (the constraint is enforced by unique index).

Comment: I'm not even sure if this is exactly the problem, the dataset is so small it's hard to tell exactly what he's wanting.

Comment: I agree with your suggestion (made the comment myself). I just don't agree with your wording "do not need a constraing - just an index" - both wind up doing the same thing. He/She just needs to _add_ another unique "constraint". Whether or not the one on `key1, key` is necessary is impossible to tell.